# CasperJS sends empty POST data to endpoint

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to scrape a site, build a JSON object to organize the info scraped, and then POSTing such JSON object to a service (in PHP) that ETLs the info into a database.

Here's the problem, whenever I try to send the JSON Object the, the object is empty, this is the code I'm using to send the info.

```
casper.then(function(){
    var productDetails = {};
    this.each(products,function(self, product){
        self.thenOpen(product, function(a){
            productDetails = this.evaluate(getProductDetails);
        });
        self.thenOpen('http://localhost.endpoint.lan/saveScrapingData.php', {
            method:'post',
            data: {
                name:'Alan',
                info: productDetails
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the problem is that productDetails is being sent as empty, and I don't know why because if I `console.log` the variable at this point:

```
self.thenOpen(product, function(a){
    productDetails = this.evaluate(getProductDetails);
});
```

the variable is not empty, more than likely this is a racing condition. The variable is being sent before it contains any data, but I don't understand why is this happening, if I'm sending the data after I'm sure the variable contains data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at the time of calling `thenOpen` the `productDetails` variable is still undefined. You can just split the `thenOpen` call into `then` and `open` so that it is defined when `open` is actually called.

```js
self.then(function(){
    this.open('http://localhost.endpoint.lan/saveScrapingData.php', {
        method:'post',
        data: {
            name:'Alan',
            info: productDetails
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
});
```

This is because of the asynchronous manner of casper steps (`then*` or `wait*`). They are scheduled but executed later. The problem is that by calling `thenOpen` with the settings object fixes the value of `productDetails` to `undefined` since the the previous step was not yet executed.